# Lazy loading f:selectItems when opening p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lazy-loading, selectonemenu

I would like to load list of `<f:selectItems>` only when user opens `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

I tried this way but doesn't work:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="bases" value="#{sucesoBB.suceso.base}" converter="EntitiesCachedConverter"  >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{sucesoBB.bases}" var="base" itemValue="#{base}" itemLabel="#{base.id} - #{base.descripcion}"  />
    <p:ajax event="click" onstart="#{sucesoBB.bases == null or sucesoBB.bases.size() ==1 or sucesoBB.bases.empty()?'cargaBases();':''}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:remoteCommand name="cargaBases" update="bases" actionListener="#{sucesoBB.cargaBases}" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you define `doesn't work` - any errors, unexpected behaviour?

Comment: why not just use the p:autocomplete with a dropdown function (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)? I think it would accomplish the lazy loading need.

Comment: I thought to use p:autocomplete if I can´t to do lazy p:selectOneMenu

Comment: yes. I think that will be your best option since based on the primefaces user guide there is no 'dynamic' attribute for the <p:selectonemenu>.

Answer (score 2):

A "dynamic" attribute was recently added to the selectOneMenu component.

Just add it like this: `<p:selectOneMenu dynamic="true" ... >`

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2399

**Demo:** 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

You need to have at least Primefaces version 6.0.20, 6.1.2 or 6.2